# Joint probability density function.

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have the joint density function: f (x,y) = 2 when X>0 Y>0 and X+Y<1 and 0 elsewhere. I wonder what my limits of integration are and possible the shape of the region. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I'm want to find the expected value of x and y and the variance of x and y.

Comment: Then I need to integrate

Comment: Well I do not need any help with the integration itself, only to set up the limits, which was fully written in my question

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Can anyone please confirm that E (XY) = 1/6, E (x^2) = -1/2, E (X) = 1/3 and that V (X) = -11/18. I have different answers in two different books.

Comment: [$\Bbb E[XY]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_0%5E%7B1-y%7D+2xy+dx+dy)$=\frac 1{12}$,[$\Bbb E[X^2]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_0%5E%7B1-y%7D+2x%5E2+dx+dy)$=\frac16$, [$\Bbb E[X]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_0%5E%7B1-y%7D+2x+dx+dy)$=\frac13$

Comment: For $V(X)$, did it not strike you that variance cannot be negative? You compute this by $$V(X)=\Bbb E[X^2]-\Bbb E[X]^2$$ Also, it should have been obvious that your $\Bbb E[X^2]$ was wrong, since $X^2\ge 0$, so how can its mean be negative?

Comment: Sorry it should be E (X) = 1/3 V (X)=1/18 E (X^2) = 1/6 and E (XY) = 1/12. Do you agree?

Comment: I can only see symbols and no text nor numbers in that answer

Comment: Look at the comment above it.

Comment: Do you know what the limits of integration would be if I want to find p(Y>X)? :)

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question about this - include all relevant information about the distribution that you have here, and then ask about how to find limits in general for 2 dimensional problems like this, where you have a region. It seems like this is something you're struggling with, so it could be nice to get a general answer. If you choose to ask this, comment here once you have asked it, and I will have a look. Also I will delete some of the comments above that are unnecessarily taking up space.

Comment: I've posted a new question now as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'shape of the graph'... you mean 'shape of the region'? The $X>0,Y>0$ means it's confined to the first quadrant. Then we have $Y < 1-X$ which means it is below the line $1-x$ which has both $y$ intercept and $x$ intercept $1.$ So the region is the triangle with corners $(1,0),$ $(0,0),$ $(0,1).$

When you integrate a function $f(x,y)$ over this region you can do it one of two ways: $$ \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} f(x,y) \;dy\;dx$$ or $$ \int_0^1\int_0^{1-y} f(x,y) \;dx\;dy.$$ (Well, there are more possible ways than this, but these are the only two one is likely to use.)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yes it was the shape of the region I was wondering about. Thank you :)

Comment: Can anyone please confirm that E (XY) = 1/6, E (x^2) = -1/2, E (X) = 1/3 and that V (X) = -11/18. I have different answers in two different books.

Comment: @user496975 If you feel this answer helped you, and you are happy to accept your question as "answered", feel free to press the green check mark next to the answer score. This will indicate to people who are seeing the question for the first time that there is an accepted answer.